# Hitting the request limit

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, google-chrome, browser

I'm letting users upload files from the client side (angular 4) to the server (spring boot). When he picks more than 6 files, chrome will use all 6 allowed requests at a time and he won't be able to communicate with server until there are no more than 5 files uploading.

Is there a way to reserve at least one request free for potential requests instead of using all of them? Or what should be done here?

Comment: Yes, rewrite your uploading code as an AJAX request, and limit the number of simultaneous uploads in your code.

Comment: Is there a way for angular to differentiate between upload and normal requests? I'm using Observable.concat() to fire each request observable one by one, but there is a problem if meanwhile I get a new file to be uploaded, I cannot just add it to the queue there, I need to run another Observable.concat(). Is there something in Angular that does this for me?
(some queue for uploads)

Comment: No idea what your code does now, so I can't comment

Answer (score -2):

What you're looking for is Domain Sharding.

See (first google result - no preference on the information source): https://www.keycdn.com/support/domain-sharding/

Comment: OP wants to limit the number of upload requests, not increase the number of requests

Comment: Well depends on how you read it I guess, because since he doesn't know that domain sharding is possible, he just assumed that limiting the number of requests would be the way to go. I don't think my answer is wrong compared to what you mentioned, just different solutions for the same problem really.